# drawing pixels to create movement effect in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a drag race game in QT. I want to draw lines like

https://youtu.be/KkMZI5Jbf18?list=PLwPf3vved8fj9V28pxdD2aauo470UKGUz&t=727

for the illusion of movement, but i can only draw it once with QImage, if I put it in the loop it won't even start.

```
QImage cesta(1200, 800, QImage::Format_RGB32);

for(int y=0; y<visina/2;y++)
{ for(int x=0; x<sirina;x++)
 {
     float perspective = (float)y / (visina /2.0);


     float middle = 0.5;
     float rwidth = 0.1 + perspective * 0.8; //0.6
     float cwidth = rwidth * 0.15;

     rwidth *=0.5;

     int leftgrass = (middle - rwidth - cwidth) * sirina;
     int leftclip = (middle - rwidth) * sirina;
     int rightclip = (middle + rwidth) * sirina;
     int rightgrass = (middle + rwidth + cwidth) * sirina;

     int row = 800 / 2 +y;

     QRgb grasscolor = sinf(20.0 * powf(1.0 - perspective,3) + distance * 0.1) > 0.0f ?  qRgb(0, 174, 78) : qRgb(0, 111, 16);


     if(x >=0 && x<leftgrass)
        {cesta.setPixel(x,row,grasscolor);
          QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(cesta);}
     if(x >=leftgrass && x<leftclip)
        cesta.setPixel(x,row,qRgb(255, 0, 0));

     if(x >=leftclip && x<rightclip)
        cesta.setPixel(x,row,qRgb(55, 55, 55));

     if(x >=rightclip && x<rightgrass)
        cesta.setPixel(x,row,qRgb(255, 0, 0));

     if(x >=rightgrass && x<sirina)
        {cesta.setPixel(x,row,grasscolor);
          QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(cesta);}

 }


}

QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(cesta);
 scene->addPixmap(pixmap);
```

Comment: How often do you call that code? Do you use a QTimer to call that code?

Comment: What is visina and sirina?

Comment: Please define "real time". It seems you are not familiar with how computers work. On a standard PC with your standard OS realtime is something you can only dream about.

Comment: visina = height, sirina = width @eyllanesc

Comment: @rbaleksandar by realtime i mean when the car is supposedly going forward, not actual realtime, sorry

Comment: Place a code that can be reproduced and thus observe the problem, we call that [mcve], the error may depend on how you call that code, do you use a QTimer to update the image?

Comment: I dont think that you should misuse a QImage to draw pixels in a QGraphicsScene. You should have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139847/setpixel-of-qgraphicsscene-in-qt

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to drawing this background is going to be extremely slow. There is no need to do pixel-level manipulations of QImage when all you want to do is draw a few dark green rectangles on a light green background or the other way around.

It looks like this is to be included in a QGraphicsScene. If so, I'd simply subclass a QGraphicsRectItem. Reimplement its paint method to first fill the item with one color, and then draw the bands over that using the other color. Each band can be drawn as a single rectangle. The positions and sizes of the bands should be different based on some progress value that you can then animate according to the speed. With each progress change, you then call update on your graphics item for the whole item so the framework will schedule a redraw.

If this were a QML thing, I'd say implement your own QML item and use a shader to do the drawing. That would be the fastest solution by far, and the drawing is simple enough to fully calculate in a shader.